# How to exit from ForEach-Object in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, foreach

I have the following code:

```
$project.PropertyGroup | Foreach-Object {
    if($_.GetAttribute('Condition').Trim() -eq $propertyGroupConditionName.Trim()) {
        $a = $project.RemoveChild($_);
        Write-Host $_.GetAttribute('Condition')"has been removed.";
    }
};
```

Question #1: How do I exit from ForEach-Object? I tried using "break" and "continue", but it doesn't work.

Question #2: I found that I can alter the list within a `foreach` loop... We can't do it like that in C#... Why does PowerShell allow us to do that?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

First of all, `Foreach-Object` is **not** an actual loop and calling `break` in it will cancel the whole script rather than skipping to the statement after it.

Conversely, `break` and `continue` will work as you expect in an actual `foreach` loop.

Item #1. Putting a `break` within the `foreach` loop does exit the loop, but it does not stop the pipeline. It sounds like you want something like this:

```
$todo=$project.PropertyGroup 
foreach ($thing in $todo){
    if ($thing -eq 'some_condition'){
        break
    }
}
```

Item #2. PowerShell lets you modify an array within a `foreach` loop over that array, but those changes do not take effect until you exit the loop. Try running the code below for an example.

```
$a=1,2,3
foreach ($value in $a){
  Write-Host $value
}
Write-Host $a
```

I can't comment on why the authors of PowerShell allowed this, but most other scripting languages ([Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl), [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) and shell) allow similar constructs.

Comment: I think you meant to add a line like, `$a = 1..23;` in your loop to show that changes aren't reflected mid-loop execution.

Comment: Item #2 is incorrect (at least with v5 with a fixed sized array).  You can modify the array and have it visible within the `ForEach` construct.  If you were to add `$a[1] = 9` inside of the `ForEach` construct, it will show 9 as the 2nd element, but you cannot add/remove elements from the array, and anything you add using the `+=` operator will not be shown until the end.  If not a fixed sized array (i.e. `$a=[System.Collections.ArrayList]@(1,2,3)`) then any attempt to modify the contents will cause `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.` error, terminating the loop.

Comment: This is an entirely incorrect answer.  The question is in regards to `Foreach-Object`.  In powershell (majorly annoying gotcha btw) `foreach` is an "operator" and an "alias." `foreach` provided in this answer by smeltplate is the "operator" and not the "alias".  See [here.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/07/08/getting-to-know-foreach-and-foreach-object/)  Note: this answer is an entire refactoring of code and may not work for many situations.

Comment: @JamieMarshall Yes, you are absolutely correct. break in a ForEach-Object loop ends the whole script in my test cases

Comment: This doesn't work for me - I get a Break Exception on `Get-ADGroupMember`

Answer (score 48):

There are differences between `foreach` and `foreach-object`.

A very good description you can find here: [MS-ScriptingGuy](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/07/08/getting-to-know-foreach-and-foreach-object/)

For testing in PS, here you have scripts to show the difference.

ForEach-Object:

```
# Omit 5.
1..10 | ForEach-Object {
if ($_ -eq 5) {return}
# if ($_ -ge 5) {return} # Omit from 5.
Write-Host $_
}
write-host "after1"
```

```
# Cancels whole script at 15, "after2" not printed.
11..20 | ForEach-Object {
if ($_ -eq 15) {continue}
Write-Host $_
}
write-host "after2"
```

```
# Cancels whole script at 25, "after3" not printed.
21..30 | ForEach-Object {
if ($_ -eq 25) {break}
Write-Host $_
}
write-host "after3"
```

foreach

```
# Ends foreach at 5.
foreach ($number1 in (1..10)) {
if ($number1 -eq 5) {break}
Write-Host "$number1"
}
write-host "after1"
```

```
# Omit 15. 
foreach ($number2 in (11..20)) {
if ($number2 -eq 15) {continue}
Write-Host "$number2"
}
write-host "after2"
```

```
# Cancels whole script at 25, "after3" not printed.
foreach ($number3 in (21..30)) {
if ($number3 -eq 25) {return}
Write-Host "$number3"
}
write-host "after3"
```

Comment: This is a proper answer. It explains commandlet ForEach-Object‚ as in question. Example uses its alias foreach, but still it is commandlet.

Accepted answer works, but it explains keyword foreach. I know PowerShell is confusing in this matter, but still these are two different things.

Comment: I spent so many hours debugging code, wondering why `break` was breaking out of my whole script, instead of just the `ForEach-Object` loop, until I finally found this answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

To stop the pipeline of which `ForEach-Object` is part just use the statement `continue` inside the script block under `ForEach-Object`. `continue` behaves differently when you use it in `foreach(...) {...}` and in `ForEach-Object {...}` and this is why it's possible. If you want to carry on producing objects in the pipeline discarding some of the original objects, then the best way to do it is to filter out using `Where-Object`.

Comment: +1.  Interesting.  I never knew this.  It seems to work the same whether you use `break` or `continue`.  I wonder why this didn't work for the author of the question since they said they tried both.

Comment: Any idea where this is documented?  [`about_break`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_break) and [`about_continue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_continue) only talk about `for`, `foreach`, `while`, and `switch` statements.  [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) makes no mention of `break` or `continue`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me - I get a Continue Exception on `Get-ADGroupMember`

Comment: Continue can break the execution of a parent loop in this case. See explainations here : https://powershell.org/forums/topic/best-way-to-break-out-of-foreach-loop/#post-19909

Comment: The link is now https://forums.powershell.org/t/best-way-to-break-out-of-foreach-loop/3289/3

Answer (score 11):

There is a way to break from `ForEach-Object` without throwing an exception. It employs a lesser-known feature of `Select-Object`, using the `-First` [parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.1#parameters), which actually breaks the pipeline when the specified number of pipeline items have been processed.

Simplified example:

```
$null = 1..5 | ForEach-Object {

    # Do something...
    Write-Host $_
 
    # Evaluate "break" condition -> output $true
    if( $_ -eq 2 ) { $true }  
 
} | Select-Object -First 1     # Actually breaks the pipeline
```

Output:

```text
1
2
```

Note that the assignment to `$null` is there to hide the output of `$true`, which is produced by the break condition. The value `$true` could be replaced by `42`, `"skip"`, `"foobar"`, you name it. We just need to pipe something to `Select-Object` so it breaks the pipeline.

Answer (score 9):

Since `ForEach-Object` is a [cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-6), `break` and `continue` will behave differently here than with the `foreach` [keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-6). Both will stop the loop but will also terminate the entire script:

**break:**

```
0..3 | foreach {
    if ($_ -eq 2) { break }
    $_
}
echo "Never printed"

# OUTPUT:
# 0
# 1
```

**continue:**

```
0..3 | foreach {
    if ($_ -eq 2) { continue }
    $_
}
echo "Never printed"

# OUTPUT:
# 0
# 1
```

So far, I have not found a "good" way to break a foreach script block without breaking the script, except "abusing" exceptions, although [powershell core uses this approach](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/883ca98dd74ea13b3d8c0dd62d301963a40483d6/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/Select-Object.cs#L725):

**throw:**

```
class CustomStopUpstreamException : Exception {}
try {
    0..3 | foreach {
        if ($_ -eq 2) { throw [CustomStopUpstreamException]::new() }
        $_
    }
} catch [CustomStopUpstreamException] { }
echo "End"

# OUTPUT:
# 0
# 1
# End
```

The alternative (which is not always possible) would be to use the `foreach` *keyword*:

**foreach:**

```
foreach ($_ in (0..3)) {
    if ($_ -eq 2) { break }
    $_
}
echo "End"

# OUTPUT:
# 0
# 1
# End
```

Comment: It turns out that your "throw" example is how [powershell core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/883ca98dd74ea13b3d8c0dd62d301963a40483d6/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/Select-Object.cs#L725) does it. So I think it's the only solution really. I tried to figure out how to use the `System.Management.Automation.StopUpstreamCommandsException`, but couldn't quite figure out how. But I guess throwing a specific exception and only catching that exception could make it so that you don't ignore other exceptions

Comment: It will probably confuse readers that you used `foreach` alias for `ForEach-Object` since your answer covers differences between the two

Comment: @JasonS That is really the point of the answer, to show they look alike but behave differently, and I hope I sufficiently described the differences. It can only be beneficial to train your eye to spot which one it is, since real-world scripts won't go easy on you either.

Comment: @marsze oh, I see your point now in intentionally making it real world where readability often falls by the wayside. I guess I just thought some readers, here for help, still won't realise one of those `foreach` is an unfortunate alias to `ForEach-Object`

Comment: @JoelPearson you can certainly do it if you write a binary cmdlet https://gist.github.com/santisq/85e322d0e88545b60bb7dcd70af26c4b#file-testanycommand-cs-L34-L39

Answer (score 6):

If you **insist** on using *ForEach-Object*, then I would suggest adding a "break condition" like this:

```
$Break = $False;

1,2,3,4 | Where-Object { $Break -Eq $False } | ForEach-Object {

    $Break = $_ -Eq 3;

    Write-Host "Current number is $_";
}
```

The above code must output 1,2,3 and then skip (break before) 4. Expected output:

```
Current number is 1
Current number is 2
Current number is 3
```

Comment: this is the best answer. I found that if you have some outer loop, such as a while loop, and a cmdlet that will never stop generating objects unless you break or constrain it ahead of time, then you cannot simply halt the pipeline without escaping the while loop...and you must use a pipeline to have a correct implementation. This provides a way to halt the pipeline without escaping the outer scope. Great. Escaping the outer scope with a break is probably a bug.

Comment: Thank you @Chris - yes. It's a neat way of dealing with the need to break the loop, whilst benefiting from the features that would otherwise be unavailable outside of the pipe.

Answer (score 4):

Below is a suggested approach to Question #1 which I use if I wish to use the ForEach-Object cmdlet.
It does not directly answer the question because it does not EXIT the pipeline.
However, it may achieve the desired effect in Q#1.
The only drawback an amateur like myself can see is when processing large pipeline iterations.

```
    $zStop = $false
    (97..122) | Where-Object {$zStop -eq $false} | ForEach-Object {
    $zNumeric = $_
    $zAlpha = [char]$zNumeric
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow ("{0,4} = {1}" -f ($zNumeric, $zAlpha))
    if ($zAlpha -eq "m") {$zStop = $true}
    }
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "My PSVersion = 5.1.18362.145"
```

Comment: Wow. It really helps to get out of an unstoppable pipe. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for "Where-Object" just what I needed. X

Answer (score 3):

I found this question while looking for a way to have fine grained flow control to break from a specific block of code. The solution I settled on wasn't mentioned...

### Using labels with the break keyword

From: [about_break](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_break?view=powershell-7)

> A Break statement can include a label that lets you exit embedded
>   loops. A label can specify any loop keyword, such as Foreach, For, or
>   While, in a script.

Here's a simple example

```
:myLabel for($i = 1; $i -le 2; $i++) {
        Write-Host "Iteration: $i"
        break myLabel
}

Write-Host "After for loop"

# Results:
# Iteration: 1
# After for loop
```

And then a more complicated example that shows the results with nested labels and breaking each one.

```
:outerLabel for($outer = 1; $outer -le 2; $outer++) {

    :innerLabel for($inner = 1; $inner -le 2; $inner++) {
        Write-Host "Outer: $outer / Inner: $inner"
        #break innerLabel
        #break outerLabel
    }

    Write-Host "After Inner Loop"
}

Write-Host "After Outer Loop"

# Both breaks commented out
# Outer: 1 / Inner: 1
# Outer: 1 / Inner: 2
# After Inner Loop
# Outer: 2 / Inner: 1
# Outer: 2 / Inner: 2
# After Inner Loop
# After Outer Loop

# break innerLabel Results
# Outer: 1 / Inner: 1
# After Inner Loop
# Outer: 2 / Inner: 1
# After Inner Loop
# After Outer Loop

# break outerLabel Results
# Outer: 1 / Inner: 1
# After Outer Loop
```

You can also adapt it to work in other situations by wrapping blocks of code in loops that will only execute once.

```
:myLabel do {
    1..2 | % {

        Write-Host "Iteration: $_"
        break myLabel

    }
} while ($false)

Write-Host "After do while loop"

# Results:
# Iteration: 1
# After do while loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to abruptly exit out of `ForEach-Object` pipeline in PowerShell:

1. Apply exit logic in `Where-Object` first, then pass objects to `Foreach-Object`,  or
2. (where possible) convert `Foreach-Object` into a standard `Foreach` looping construct.

Let's see examples: Following scripts exit out of Foreach-Object loop after 2nd iteration (i.e. pipeline iterates only 2 times)":

**Solution-1**: use `Where-Object` filter BEFORE `Foreach-Object`:

```
[boolean]$exit = $false;
1..10 | Where-Object {$exit -eq $false} | Foreach-Object {
     if($_ -eq 2) {$exit = $true}    #OR $exit = ($_ -eq 2);
     $_;
}
```

OR

```
1..10 | Where-Object {$_ -le 2} | Foreach-Object {
     $_;
}
```

**Solution-2**: Converted `Foreach-Object` into standard `Foreach` looping construct:

```
Foreach ($i in 1..10) { 
     if ($i -eq 3) {break;}
     $i;
}
```

PowerShell should really provide a bit more straightforward way to exit or *break* out ***from within the body*** of a `Foreach-Object` pipeline. **Note**: `return` doesn't exit, it only skips specific iteration (similar to `continue` in most programming languages), here is an example of `return`:

```
Write-Host "Following will only skip one iteration (actually iterates all 10 times)";
1..10 | Foreach-Object {
     if ($_ -eq 3) {return;}  #skips only 3rd iteration.
     $_;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While this is a bit hacky, it works:

```
$array = 'a'..'z'
:pipe do{
    $array | ForEach-Object {
        $_
        if ($_ -eq 'c') {
            break :pipe
        }
    }
} until ($true)
```

***Output***:
`a`
`b`
`c`

The code can also be condensed easily, like so:

```
$array = 'a'..'z'
:_ do{ $array | ForEach-Object {
    $_
    if ($_ -eq 'c') {
        break :_
    }
}}until(1)

# OR:
#}}until({})
# not sure why {} evaluates to True, but whatever
# anything that evaluates to True will work, e.g.: !''
```

Answer (score -1):

Answer for Question #1 -
You could simply have your if statement stop being TRUE

```
$project.PropertyGroup | Foreach {
    if(($_.GetAttribute('Condition').Trim() -eq $propertyGroupConditionName.Trim()) -and !$FinishLoop) {
        $a = $project.RemoveChild($_);
        Write-Host $_.GetAttribute('Condition')"has been removed.";
        $FinishLoop = $true
    }
};
```

Comment: The problem is that this doesn't stop the loop; it will just evaluate to `$false` over and over again (this will be pretty slow for very large and/or expensive collections).

Comment: Yeah, the way you do it, is not what the author asked for. Your pipeline is run from the beginning to the very end for each and every object fed into the pipeline. It does not stop it midway but just stops creating output for some of the objects, still consuming them which can be very costly if there are many of them. That's definitely not what the author asked for.