# Return to outer loop in PowerShell when matching conditions

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm writing a simple PowerShell script to get all the users from a specific OU in [Active Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) (AD) and all the folders from a directory, then compare each username with each foldername to verify that the user has a folder there, and do something.

The script shown below works fine, but when it matches the strings, I want it to break and return to the outer `For-EachObject`, switching the username. (It's not necessary to verify the rest of the list if it already found one), but the break is breaking the entire script, it just ends.

```
$PerfilFolder = Get-ChildItem $FileServerPath | Sort
Get-ADUser -SearchBase $SB -Filter * | Sort SamAccountName | % {
    $UserName = $_.SamAccountName
    $PerfilFolder | % {
        if($UserName -match (($_.Name).Split(".")[0])){
            #Match!
            #Do something
            break
        }
    }
}
```

I already tried `return` and `continue`, but all of them have the same behavior. What should I do?

Also general improvements tips are welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Do{} While()` loop:

```
$PerfilFolder = Get-ChildItem $FileServerPath | Sort
Get-ADUser -SearchBase $SB -Filter * | Sort SamAccountName | % {
    $UserName = $_.SamAccountName
    $NoMatch = $true
    Do{$PerfilFolder | % {
        if ($UserName -match (($_.Name).Split(".")[0])){
            #Match!
            #Do something
            $NoMatch = $false
        }
    } While($NoMatch)
}
```

I am pretty sure that'll end your loop where you want it to. That answers the question, but it really doesn't solve your problem if that's what you're really trying to do. I think including a `Where` statement would serve you better:

```
    Do{$PerfilFolder | Where{$UserName -match (($_.Name).Split(".")[0])} |
        %{
            #Match!
            #Do something
            $NoMatch = $false
        }
    } While($NoMatch)
```

That may well make the `Do{} While()` unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks! A simple Where solved the problem, forgot about that. Do{}While() is a good option too.

Answer (score 0):

Check smeltplate's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277994/powershell-how-to-exit-from-foreach-object). It seems your break perfectly exits the foreach loop, but not the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I usually avoid this by setting up two sets of objects, and then filtering one on the property of the other.

```
$PerfilFolder = Get-ChildItem $FileServerPath | Sort
foreach ($user in Get-ADUser -SearchBase $SB -Filter * | Sort SamAccountName){
   $matchingFolder = $PerfilFolder | ? {$user.SamAccountName -match (($_.Name).Split(".")[0])
   if (($matchingFolder | Measure-Object).Count -gt 0){
       #do something to $matchingFolder | Select -First 1
   }
   else {
       # Do something else
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you too, your script also helped me.