# Powershell: "break" seems to end whole program, not just a loop?

Tags: powershell, break, pipeline

I have this script:

```
1..10|%{
    $_
    if(($_ % 3) -eq 0)
    {
     "wow"
     break
    }
}

"hello"
```

I expect from 1 to 10, when meeting 3 it prints"wow", and finally "hello"
But actual output is:

```
1
2
3
kkk
```

So "break" seems to break not the %{} loop in pipeline, but broke the whole program? How can I break in the loop, while keep executing later statements?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to exit from ForEach-Object in PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277994/how-to-exit-from-foreach-object-in-powershell)

Comment: It should print "wow" at 6 and 9 also, but nevertheless, `break` does exit the script altogether. `return` doesn't help either, so this is no duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ForEach-Object` and `foreach` loop are different. If you use the latter everything should work as you expect.

```
foreach ($n in (1..10)){
    $n
    if(($n % 3) -eq 0)
    {
     "wow";
     break;
    }
}

"hello"
```

The output would be

```
1
2
3
wow
hello
```

UPD: You can read some helpful info about the differences [here](http://blog.pluralsight.com/what-you-need-to-know-about-foreach-loops-in-powershell). The main thing to point attention to is that the `Foreach-Object` is integrated into the pipeline, it's basically a function with the `process` block inside. The `foreach` is a statement. Naturally, `break` can behave differently.