# How can I search all files in a directory for a list of strings(numbers)?

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a list of numbers in a csv formatted like this:

```
po
123
456
789
```

I also have a directory with 100+ documents. I need to check each document for each string in the csv. If one of the numbers is in one of the documents, it needs to move it to a different file. This is what I have so far:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "\\wh1-app\SPS EDI\ARCHIVE IN\*.txt"


foreach ($file in $files) {

    $file = Get-Content $file

    $pos = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\ttilton\Desktop\pos.csv -OutVariable string -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    foreach ($po in $pos) {

       $containsWord = $file | %{$_ -match $po.po}

        if ($containsWord -contains $true){ 

            write-host $file + " is " + $po.po

            #Copy-Item $file C:\Users\ttilton\Desktop\pos\

        }
    }
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. It's running without error, but its not really doing anything.

Any ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: Change ErrorAction to Stop so you can see possible exceptions occurring.

Comment: The `Copy-Item` will not be executed, as the `#` turns the whole line into a comment.

Comment: @C.Helling As far as I understand the code `$containsWord` is an array of boolean values. With your suggestion the ìf` clause would always be true.

Comment: @ManuelBatsching Valid point, I've amended my comment. Still unsure what `$po.po` is supposed to be though.

Comment: @ManuelBatsching I know it won't be executed, I just wanted to check that it was working with the write-host first, but nothing is printing out. and I KNOW that there are matches in that directory.

Comment: Reusing `$file` for both the name and the content is confusing, but overall I can't see anything wrong. Run it in the PowerShell ISE debugger - does it find any *.txt files? Does Import-Csv actually import any data? Does `$po.po` become the right numbers you expect? You could do the same thing with `$nums = (import-csv ___).po -join '|';  select-string -pattern $nums -path "\\wh1-app\SPS EDI\ARCHIVE IN\*.txt"`

Comment: @C.Helling import-csv returns an array of objects with properties. The badly formatted example at the top of the post shows that `po` is the column header of the csv, so each `$po in $pos` will be a pscustomobject with one property named for the column header - that is, `$po.po`

Comment: @C.Helling the $po part of $po.po is just from the foreach loop. the .po is the label of the column in the csv. without it the $po would be {po=123} instead of just 123.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler everything seems to be in working order. it does get info from both the csv and text files. It just sits there an runs though without doing anything - including errors. I am running it in the ise debugger.

Comment: Unless it's just slow - the testing of every line of every file, generating an array of number-of-lines long for every file might be enormously slow... how big are the files? Select-String should be a big improvement on that front.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler it may just be slow, there are a lot of files in the directory, the files themselves are pretty small. I'll try the select-string in a few minutes. Thanks!

Comment: @tyTil Select-String should be significantly faster, but change your code to use `$containsWord = $file | ?{$_ -match $po.po} | select -first 1` and then check `if ($containsWord)` should reduce the amount of work considerably - only testing until the first found thing and not keeping something for every line. And try some "write-host" in each loop, to show you the current $po and current $file so you can see how fast it's progressing.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler that definitely sped things up! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

For what I have test it should work and I guess that there is something wrong with the (accessibility) of you remote location (`\\wh1-app\SPS EDI\ARCHIVE IN\*.txt`) that contains your `.txt` files.

To troubleshoot this I would either put a few of the source files local (e.g. `C:\temp\*.txt`)

Or add you additional `Write-Host` commands in your script. e.g. here:

```
...
foreach ($file in $files) {
    Write-Host $file.name    # Is there really a file picked up here?
    $file = Get-Content $file
    ...
```

Some general recommendations to speedup you function:

- put `$pos = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\ttilton\Desktop\pos.csv -OutVariable string -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` out of the `foreach ($file in $files) {...` loop, you only need to read the `.csv` file once.
- Do not (continue to) read the `.txt` if you found a match (one single `$True` in `$containsWord` is enough to validate `if ($containsWord -contains $true){...`. To stop a ForEach loop see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10420522/1701026

Comment: Yeah I've taken a chunk of files out and am now running on it locally. It's still slow, but works better that before thanks to the advice offered by    
@TessellatingHeckler in the comments above. Thanks!