# PowerShell 6 Break from ForEach-Object Loop without exiting script

Tags: powershell

I have a fairly complex ForEach-Object loop. It is processing a lot of information. For testing, I want to stop it after a number of iterations. This is triggered by the `if (!$live -and $count -gt 10)` I have tried using `break`, `exit`, and `continue`. All of them exit the script entirely without performing any of the remaining code following the ForEach-Object. The Write-Output ("Success") is just the first example.

I have managed to work around this by using an empty If statement and wrapping the rest of the contents in an Else, but his seems a cludge. Can anyone help me understand why this is not behaving the way I expect it to?

```
$update_list | ForEach-Object { 
  $count ++
  if (!$live -and $count -gt 10){
    continue
  } 
  $id = $_.event_id
  if ($_.app_username) {  
    $user = $_.app_username 
    $body = "stuff"

    Write-Output ("Begin $count of $total")
    Write-Output ("Sending: stuff `r`n")

    #Get the current owner
    $test_owner_before = stuff

    #Check to see if it is the same as the user we are going to send.
    #If it is then skip
    if ($test_owner_before.object_ownership.object.owner_username -eq $user) {
      $correct += [pscustomobject]@{event_id = $id; owner_username = $test_owner; provided_username = $user}  
      Write-Output ("The current owner $($test_owner_before.object_ownership.object.owner_username) matches the proposed owner $user - Skipping.")
    }

    #Otherwise send the update
    else {
      #Only make changes if the -live flag has been set
      if ($live){
        $response = stuff
      }

      #Get the current owner
      $test_owner_after = stuff
      $test_owner = $test_owner_after.object_ownership.object.owner_username

      #Check to be sure the current owner matches the user we sent
      #If so then report success
      if ($test_owner -eq $user -and $user -in $userid_username_list.app_username){
        Write-Output ("Success")
        Write-Output ("Current Owner $($test_owner) matches the sent sent owner $user and is found in the 25Live user list")
        $match += [pscustomobject]@{event_id = $id; owner_username = $test_owner; provided_username = $user}  
      }

      #If not report the error and details
      else {
        Write-Output ("Mismatch")
        Write-Output ("Current Owner $($test_owner) does not match the sent sent owner $user or is found in the 25Live user list")
        $mismatch += [pscustomobject]@{event_id = $id; owner_username = $test_owner; provided_username = $user}       
      }
      if ($response) {
        Write-Output ("Response:`r`n`t $($response.OuterXml)`r`n")
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    #If there is no Requestor Username then skip
    Write-Output ("$count of $total - No user id for Event ID: $id - Skipping.")
  }
}
Write-Output ("Success")
```

Comment: Use an actual loop statement (ie. `foreach($item in $updatelist){ ... }`) if you want proper flow control (like `break` and `continue`) :)

Comment: Interesting. I had thought `foreach` was just an alias for `ForEach-Object` but now that I am looking at the structure it makes some sense that they are not actually the same thing.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks for the link. I had looked at the accepted answer on that page and it did not answer the question. The answer that I was looking for is on that page though in this comment by marsze: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58447983/1223909